# Collapsingtoolbarlayout/recyclerview/appbarlayout is cut off

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I put an edittext on top, and it is invisible and the whole thing is cut off. I am probably mis-using collapsing toolbar layout/recyclerview/etc.

See code below:

Fragment:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="recruitr.jseeker.OnBoarding.OnBoardingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintoolbar"
            android:minHeight="128dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <recruitr.jseeker.Logic.ViewPager_NoSwipe
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </recruitr.jseeker.Logic.ViewPager_NoSwipe>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Recyclerview:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Here"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/fragment_search_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Viewpager noswipe:

```
public class ViewPager_NoSwipe extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public ViewPager_NoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

I'm trying for it to all be visible when I enter the screen.

[image: Top part is cut off]

Comment: post the code in recruitr.jseeker.Logic.ViewPager_NoSwipe

Comment: See edited code... the noswipe is just to make it not swipe